# How to read a value from XML in Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I want to read the value of author and title from the below XML using python

```
<book id="bk101">
  <author Value="J.K.Rowling" />
  <title Value="Harry Potter"/>
</book>
```

Code:

```
member.find('author').text
# returns None.
```

Comment: can you include your python code?

Comment: Code please! You want an attribute value, not text. Perhaps `member.find('author').attrib['Value']` will give you what you want.

Comment: Code should include the module you are using to parse the XML. They have different ways of addressing attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Making some assumptions on the XML library you're using, here's an example using `xml.dom.minidom`:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xml_string = """<book id="bk101">
  <author Value="J.K.Rowling" />
  <title Value="Harry Potter"/>
</book>"""

# Parse 
root = minidom.parseString(xml_string)
author_list = root.getElementsByTagName("author")

for author in author_list:
  value = author.getAttribute("Value")
  print("Found an author with value of {0}".format(value))
```

Output:

```
Found an author with value of J.K.Rowling
```